# Clever way to create image of entire terminal log?

Tags: terminal

I would like a way to execute one command, to take a "screenshot" of the entire terminal log (including lines of text that are not visible without scrolling)

Possibly an application that has this feature?

Comment: why an image in particular, would the text work?

Comment: For blogging / sharing terminal output

Comment: It's better to share terminal output as text than as image. It allows to search words in it, and copy paste interesting parts.